# broadcast packets snmp graph shape

Tags: snmp, broadcast

I recently started using OpenNMS to monitor our LAN. I found this broadcast packets graph on several devices. I'm trying understand the consistency (shape) of these data. Most other graphs, for any type of data, rarely look this "pretty", so this strikes me as atypical. My questions are: Does anyone recognize the pattern? What might be the source?
[image: graph]

Comment: Hm, i cant recognize this pattern, so will not post a answer. But can you run a packet sniffer ? This might help solve this mistery. BTW i agree that the too neat pattern means something strange is happening.

Comment: Packet sniffer is definitely my next step. I've put that aside for a bit considering the low occurrence rate and other priorities. I just imagined my graph wasn't likely (hopefully) to be unique.

Comment: Broadcast storm?  Definitely an interesting question, if you figure out what it is please post an answer.

Comment: I think I am going for measurement artifact of some kind. You have brief bursts and they are strobing through your sampling interval for some reason. A higher/different sampling rate might eliminate the diamond pattern. Admittedly, that's only half the mystery.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's all in the fuzzy math. The Y axis is packets per second, and the range is from 0 to 4 millipackets.  Since you either move a packet or you don't, millipackets is a useless measuring unit.  You are probably sampling every 5 minutes and that leaves 300 seconds for a packet to go or not go.  1 packet every 5 minutes is 1/300 or 0.0033.  Whats the max reading you saw?  3.3 millipackets.

I would bet that one broadcast packet is the arp traffic to find the host you are interrogating, and the diamond shape is a side effect of how the value is stored/averaged by OpenNMS and RRDtool.  It is intriguing that for some reason the two samples have an inverse relationship that inverts every 6 hours, but when you are dealing with tiny floats, artifacts are common.